# Custom email validation with angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, email-validation

i'am trying to implement a custom angular function to validate an email adress, 
everything's fine except when i type example@mail, the validation doesn't work and it consider the email's adress as valid

Validator.ts

```
  static emailsLenghtAndFormat(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const email = control.value;
    const responseKo = { invalid: true };
    const responseOk = null;
    const responseKoMaxLength = { maxlength: true };

    if (!email) {
      return responseOk;
    }

    if (email.length > 100) {
      return responseKoMaxLength;
    }

    const EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;

    if (email !== '' && (email.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email))) {
      return responseKo;
    }

    return responseOk;
  }
```

authent.ts

```
      this.formAuthentification = this.fb.group({
        authentification: this.fb.group(
          {
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
          },

        {
          validator: [ValidatorsCustom.emailsLenghtAndFormat]
        }
        )
      });
```

Comment: There's really only one way to validate an email - send something to that address and await a response.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the whole form group. In this case your input isn't an AbstractControl, it is a form group. Then it will stringify your form group and try to find the regex in the whole stringified formgroup.

```
static emailsLenghtAndFormat(group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
    const email = group.get('email').value;
    const responseKo = { invalid: true };
    const responseOk = null;
    const responseKoMaxLength = { maxlength: true };

    if (!email) {
      return responseOk;
    }

    if (email.length > 100) {
      return responseKoMaxLength;
    }

    const EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;

    if (email !== '' && (email.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email))) {
      return responseKo;
    }

    return responseOk;
  }
```

Comment: i removed Validators.email and Validators.maxLength(100) 
it becames  email: ['', [Validators.required,ValidatorsCustom.emailsLenghtAndFormat]] and it worked 
thanks for your response :)

Comment: mark this as answer and upvote if this solved your problem pls ;)